# std class in php

Tags: php, arrays, std

I have this string

```
array(8) {
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#871 (2) {
        ["access"]=> int(0)
        ["value"]=> string(4) "Male"
    }
    [3]=> object(stdClass)#872 (2) {
        ["access"]=> int(0)
        ["value"]=> string(2) "21"
    }
    [4]=> object(stdClass)#874 (2) {
        ["access"]=> int(0)
        ["value"]=> string(4) "sdad"
    }
    [10]=> object(stdClass)#861 (2) {
        ["access"]=> int(0)
        ["value"]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [11]=> object(stdClass)#873 (2) {
        ["access"]=> int(0)
        ["value"]=> string(11) "fds"
    }
    [17]=> object(stdClass)#875 (2) {
        ["access"]=> int(0)
        ["value"]=> string(11) "aaa"
    }
    [19]=> object(stdClass)#876 (2) {
        ["access"]=> int(0)
        ["value"]=> string(4) "this!!!"
    } [29]=> object(stdClass)#878 (2) {
        ["access"]=> int(0)
        ["value"]=> string(3) "sda"
    }
}
```

How to get string which value is 'this!!!'?
I want to save value on that place to database.

Comment: You don't have a string. You have an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's get one thing straight. You don't have a string. You have an array of objects. It is not possible (in PHP) to convert objects or arrays to strings.

If you need the value at a particular index of an array, use `$array[$index];`.

If you want the value of a particular attribute of an object, simply use `$object->attribute;`, or if you want the return value from a function, use `$object->function();`.

**In your case:**

For argument's sake, let's say you want to save the `value` attribute for the `object` at `array index` 10.  The value there is

```
[10]=> object(stdClass)#861 (2) {
    ["access"]=> int(0)
    ["value"]=> string(0) ""
}
```

So in order to access the string value for the `value` attribute of that object, you would write:

```
$val = $array[10]->value;
```

Or, if you want the string value for the `value` attribute of ALL objects, you could loop through your `array` with a `foreach`

```
foreach($array as $obj) {
    $val = $obj->value;
    $access = $obj->access;

    // do something with $val and/or $access
}
```